# get src url parameter from script tag with selenium ide

Tags: url, parameters, selenium, query-string

I am using Selenium IDE to verify some elements on a page during a test.  I have a script tag that has a dynamic SRC attribute on it.  It generates the parameters for the url based on what page design i am on.  I am trying to store the value of the parameters for this SRC attribute in Selenium IDE and can't figure out how to do it.  Thoughts??

Here is the whole script tag.  I just want the Selenium IDE to store the `DesignFamily` value.

```
<script src="/JS.aspx?DesignFamily=GSMFamily&amp;Design=GSMExtreme&amp;Version=2011-4-29-17-2-5" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the easy workaround. First create user-extension as given  [here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/08_user_extensions.html#using-user-extensions-with-selenium-ide)

Then in `user-extensions.js` add this function.

`Selenium.prototype.doStoreQueryStringParameter = function(xpath, varName) {
    var currentDocument = selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().document
    var result = currentDocument.evaluate(xpath, currentDocument, null,    XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);
    result = result.stringValue
    var str = result.split(";")[0].split("=")[1];
    storedVars[varName] = str;
};`

`storeQueryStringParameter` function should be in command dropdown after your `user-extensions.js` has been loaded.

While using this your target should be something like `//*parent tags to script*/script[n]/@src //n =1,2,3.. e.g select 2 if 2nd script inside of its of parent tag is to be used`

Comment: That worked!  I did however, need to change the `.split(";")` to a `.split("&")` as i had multiple variables and your query just returned the first value WITH the second key.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: ya, i specifically targeted "DesignFamily" :)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most graceful solution, but you can explore the use of `getHtmlSource()` available in the IDE...
Though, without extending the capability using RC, I'm not sure about parsing the needed information.